# How fast do the Ito sums converge?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

**Question set up and some motivation:**

We work over the interval $[0, T]$.

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $\sigma$ an adapted almost surely $\alpha$-Holder continuous process with uniform Holder seminorm $H$, for some $\alpha \geq 0$. Suppose also $\sigma$ is uniformly bounded with constant $M$.

We know we can write the Ito integral $\int_{0}^T \sigma_t \ dW_t$ as a limit in probability of Riemann sums - namely for any sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n$ of $[0, T]$ with mesh going to $0$, we have

$$\int_{0}^T \sigma_t \ dW_t = \lim_{|\mathcal P_n| \to 0} \sum_{a_i \in \mathcal P_n} \sigma_{a_{i}}(W_{i+1} - W_{i})$$

where the limit is in probability.

Can we get “best/worst case” bounds on the rate at which these sums converge? More precisely:

**Definitions:**

Fix $\alpha, H, M > 0$, and let $\mathcal H$ denote the set of adapted processes with uniform $\alpha$-Holder seminorm at most $H$ and uniform bound $M$. We suppress the dependence on the various constants for clarity of notation.

For a given partition $\mathcal P$, write $|\mathcal P|$ and $\|\mathcal P\|$ for $\underset{a_i \in \mathcal P}{\text{max}} \ |a_{i+1} - a_i|$ and $\underset{a_i \in \mathcal P}{\text{min}} \ |a_{i+1} - a_i|$ respectively.

Define the best case and worst case convergence rates as follows - given $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$, $\sigma \in \mathcal H$, and a sequence of partitions $\mathcal P_n$ with mesh going to $0$, define

$$C(\{ \mathcal P_n \},\varepsilon, \delta, \sigma) := \inf \big \{N \in \mathbb N \ \big |\ \mathbb P\big(| \sum_{a_i \in \mathcal P_n}[ \sigma_{a_{i}}(W_{i+1} - W_{i})] - \int_{0}^T \sigma_t \ dW_t| < \delta \big) < \varepsilon \ ,\text{ for all } n \geq N\big \}$$

Further, define the best and worst case rates $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal W$ as follows:

$$\mathcal B(\varepsilon, \delta) := \underset {\sigma \in \mathcal H}{\sup} \underset{s_k}{\sup} \underset {\{\mathcal P_n\}}{\sup} \ \|\mathcal P_{C(\{\mathcal P_n\}, \varepsilon, \delta, \sigma)}\|$$

$$\mathcal W(\varepsilon, \delta) := \underset {\sigma \in \mathcal H}{\sup} \underset {s_k}{\sup} \underset {\{\mathcal P_n\}}{\inf} \ |\mathcal P_{C(\{\mathcal P_n\}, \varepsilon, \delta, \sigma)}|$$

Where

i) The second supremum in $\mathcal B, \mathcal W$ is taken over all strictly decreasing sequences $s_k$ of positive numbers.

ii) The innermost supremum in $\mathcal B$ is taken over all sequences of partitions $\mathcal P_n$ with $\|\mathcal P_n\| = s_n$ and $|\mathcal P_n| \to 0$.

iii) The innermost infimum in $\mathcal W$ is taken over all sequences of partitions $\mathcal P_n$ with $|\mathcal P_n| = s_n$ and $|\mathcal P_n| \to 0$.

> **Question:** Given $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$, what are the values of $\mathcal B(\varepsilon, \delta)$ and $\mathcal W(\varepsilon, \delta)$?

*Note: By construction, these values will depend only on $T$, $M$, $H$, $\alpha$, $\varepsilon$, and $\delta$.*

**Remarks:**

Denote by $E(\mathcal P)$ the error $| \sum_{a_i \in \mathcal P}[ \sigma_{a_{i}}(W_{i+1} - W_{i})] - \int_{0}^T \sigma_t \ dW_t|$.

It is straightforward to show that by the Ito isometry we have the following $L^2$ bound on $E(\mathcal P)$:

$$\mathbb E[E(\mathcal P)^2] \leq T H^2 |\mathcal P|^{2\alpha}$$

and so by Holder’s inequality we obtain an $L^1$ bound, and then by Markov inequality a bound in probability:

$$\mathbb P(E(\mathcal P) > \delta) \leq \frac{H |\mathcal P|^{\alpha} \sqrt T}{\delta}.$$

And hence we conclude

$$\mathcal W(\varepsilon, \delta) \geq \ \big (\frac{\varepsilon \delta}{H \sqrt T} \big )^\frac {1}{\alpha}.$$

However this bound is likely far from being sharp. How might we do better?